# How to get android default dial pad call disconnect button click event

Tags: android, callback, phone-call, telecommunication, telecom-manager

I try to get default dial pad call disconnect button click for get call state Ex: Active, disconnecting , disconnected and ect..

I need call state without using InCallService class .Because IncallService class only response for Custom dial app. May you help me for Suitable answer. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you may want to look at the Android PhoneStateListener class:

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener

Assuming you are in an active call you will see the state change to idle when the user ends the call by hitting the call disconnect button.

```
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Check that you have permissions for the particular info you need:

> Note that access to some telephony information is permission-protected. Your application won't receive updates for protected information unless it has the appropriate permissions declared in its manifest file. Where permissions apply, they are noted in the appropriate LISTEN_ flags.

If you want to actually intercept the button click and do something other than end the call, this is not supported AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i need proper active,disconnected,disconnecting and end . without using InCallService. You answer only give three states . And i also spend 3 to 4 days  for state finding work. but not able to find